Facing cyptographic checksum error
I am randomly however very very frequently facing the following error while running query from pro*c.
Pro*C is running on the same Linux as the Oracle DB so network should not be an issue.
SQL Code [-12599], Msg : [ORA-12599: TNS:cryptographic checksum mismatch]
My sqlnet.ora file is as follows:
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER=REQUIRED
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER=REQUIRED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER=(AES256,AES192,AES128)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER=(SHA1)
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_CLIENT=REQUIRED
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_CLIENT=REQUIRED
SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_CLIENT=(AES256,AES192,AES128)
SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_CLIENT=(SHA1)
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 20

I am not a DBA, however trying to resolve the challenge. Will it cause any major complication if we change the ENCRYPTION parameters to NO ENCRYPTION/ NOT REQUIRED.
Note - Oracle DB is hosted on Oracle cloud and the SQLNET config came out of the box.
